# How to run OpenDNS updater silently

Tags: opendns

Is it possible to run OpenDNS in such a way that the user does not see the updater popping up  and saying that the IP address was updated?

Comment: Curious... I never get notified that the IP address was updated. Only if I manually check the "IP updates history" can I see when it changed (and I'm not set to run hidden).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://www.opendns.com/support/dynamic_ip_windows/) for the Windows Dynamic IP Updater client, there is a [Hidden Mode](http://www.opendns.com/support/dynamic_ip_windows/#hidden):

> Even if you close the program window, it shows its icon in the system
>   tray area of Windows task bar. You can make the program even more
>   hidden by choosing "Run hidden" menu item from contextual menu in
>   system tray icon.
>
> When running in hidden mode, you can see status window by launching
>   the program from Start menu.

You may also want to consider [Disabling Error Notifications](http://www.opendns.com/support/dynamic_ip_windows/#notification):

> When an error happens, the program will notify you by showing status
>   window with error message describing the problem. Sometimes this might
>   happen often and be distracting. You can disable those notifications
>   by clicking "Stop nagging me" link present after error message. You
>   can re-enable notifications by clicking "Start nagging me" link.
>
> Please note that by disabling notifications about problems you might
>   miss a configuration problem.

Comment: But how do you turn OFF hidden mode?  I don't see some kind of ini file in the install folder.  It must be somewhere or in the registry?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way in the official version, but there are alternative clients listed on [this page](http://www.opendns.com/support/dynamic_ip_downloads/#). Alternatively the protocol is open if you're comfortable writing your own or writing a script.